# How is the order of processes killed in cgroup v2 when out-of-memory?

Tags: kill, cgroups, out-of-memory

I'm using cgroup v2 on Ubuntu 22.04 to limits users in a group. I'm wondering how the processes are killed when out-of-memory (OOM).

For an instance:

The computer has 100G memory. I have a group of 4 users -- A, B, C, and D. The group has a limit of 80G memory, that is all 4 user cannot exceed 80G.

First, user A runs a program using 50G memory (process a). After a while, B uses 20G (b), and then C takes another 20G (c). Now D begins to run a program needs 20G (d).

In the above situation, when OOM happens, whose process would be killed due to memory limitation? Which one of a, b, c, d would be killed first?

I'd found that the process possesses the most memory would be killed in cgroup v1 (https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/memory.html). Is it also in cgroup v2?

Thanks for all your help.